# property has the same value after setting it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, panel

Q:

I have a panel the visibility = false in the `.aspx` file ,at some point in my code i set the visibility = true.but **the problem is**: when i trace the code i find the visible property still equal false ,although i set it to true .
My panel name is :`pnl_DetailsGeneral`

```
 protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "2")
            {
                drp_Week.Enabled = false;
                gv_Details.Visible = false;
                panel_rmv.Visible = false;
                pnl_DetailsGeneral.Visible = true;//Here when i put a break point and after setting visible to true i find `pnl_DetailsGeneral.Visible = false`
                gv_DetailsGeneral.Visible = true;
                BindGridGeneral();

            }
            else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                drp_Week.Enabled = true;
                gv_Details.Visible = true;
                gv_DetailsGeneral.Visible = false;
                pnl_DetailsGeneral.Visible = false;
                if (drp_Week.SelectedValue != "-1")
                {

                    BindGrid();
                }
            }
        }
```

what may cause this problem?

Comment: Have you got AutoPostBack="true" on your RadioButtonList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visible property has a special property: when you read the value it not only reports on the control itself but also on it's parent. The value you get is the "real" visibility.

So apparently the parent of your control is still invisible!

When you set the parent to Visible, your control will become visible also.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `Control.Visible` property returns false if any parent has Visible = false.

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation is implicit visibility through the control hierarchy.

For instance, if you have a placeholder than contains other controls, and the placeholder has visible set to false, all of it's child controls will also have Visible set the false, even if you set the property explicitly yourself.