# properties indicate to the control and its parents

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, panel

Q:

Lately,i asked about an issue concerning setting the (`Visible`)property ,when i set it to true , i surprised in tracing after setting it to true.that its value is still false. the answer was a surprise for me :

```
 - "The Visible property has a special
   property: when you read the value it
   not only reports on the control
   itself but also on it's parent. The
   value you get is the "real"
   visibility."
```

My question is : is there any property, you meet before behave in the same manner like (`Visible`)? and how we should use them in the best way?

Comment: What do you mean .. not clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729069/property-has-the-same-value-after-setting-it

I want all the properties behave like (`Visible`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know, try this query:

```
var lst =Control.Properties.Where(p => HasSimilarBehaviourToVisibleProperty(p));
```

You just need to write `HasBehaviourLikeVisibleProperty` method.

Note: You might need reflection to get all properties. (Have a look [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/) to get properties)

Answer (score 1):

**Enabled** could be one property in this fashion.